# Get value in XML file through absolute value in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an absolute path for the values of XML files I want to retrieve. The absolute path is in the format of "A/B/C". How can I do this in Python?

Comment: By absolute path, do you mean [XPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)?

Comment: Yeah, I mean XPATH

Answer (score 3):

Using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library (Note that my answer uses core python library while the other answers are using external libraries.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<ROOT><A><B><C>The Value</C></B></A></ROOT>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('./A/B/C').text)
```

output

```
The Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

# Basic
xml = '''<ROOT><A><B><C>The Value</C></B></A></ROOT>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
print (doc.select('A>B>C'))

# Multiple
xml = '''<ROOT><A><B><C>The Value 1</C></B></A><A><B><C>The Value 2</C></B></A></ROOT>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
# print (doc.selects('A').select('B').select('C'))
print (doc.selects('A').select('B>C'))

# Mixed structure
xml = '''<ROOT><A><other>no B</other></A><A><other></other><B>no C</B></A><A><B><C>The Value</C></B></A></ROOT>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
nodes = doc.selects('A').selects('B').select('C')
for node in nodes:
  for c in node:
    if c:
      print (c)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'C', 'html': 'The Value'}
[{'tag': 'C', 'html': 'The Value 1'}, {'tag': 'C', 'html': 'The Value 2'}]
{'tag': 'C', 'html': 'The Value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) which you can install via `pip install lxml`.
See also https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

```py
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

data = '''\
<prestashop>
  <combination>
    <id>a</id>
    <id_product>b</id_product>
    <location>c</location>
    <ean13>d</ean13>
    <isbn>e</isbn>
    <upc>f</upc>
    <mpn>g</mpn>
  </combination>
</prestashop>
'''

xpath = '/prestashop/combination/ean13'

f = StringIO(data)

tree = etree.parse(f)

matches = tree.xpath(xpath)
for e in matches:
    print(e.text)
```